# python win32com - accessing Visio Custom Stencils

Tags: python, win32com, visio

I have an example of how to add some Basic shapes to a Visio document while Visio is already open, but I am interested in accessing my own custom stencils which are in the More Shapes-> My Shapes tab on visio. I would have thought that I could just extend the below example to include the More Shapes path by replacing

```
stnObj = appVisio.Documents("Basic Shapes.vss")
```

with

```
stnObj = appVisio.Documents("More Shapes\My Shapes\mycustomStencil.vss")
```

but I keep getting an error at the line where I try to open the stencil because I'm getting the pathing wrong somehow.

Message=(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Drawing4 - Visio Professional', '\n\nThis file name is not valid.', None, 0, -2032466859), None)

This is the example I'm working off which seems to work just fine working with Basic Shapes. Note that Visio has to be open already when running the code. Anyone have an idea on how to programmatically access your own custom stencils with Python?

```
import win32com.client

appVisio = win32com.client.Dispatch("Visio.Application")
doc = appVisio.Documents.Add("Basic Diagram.vst")
pagObj = doc.Pages.Item(1)
stnObj = appVisio.Documents("Basic Shapes.vss")

shpObj1 = pagObj.Drop(stnObj.Masters("Square"), 4, 7)
shpObj1.Text = "Square text"
```

Comment: Where stored these custom stencils ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes ago i asked [same question](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=9933.msg45501#msg45501).
We must use syntax like for convert stencil's path to [raw string](https://www.codevscolor.com/python-raw-string):

```
appVisio.Documents.Open (r'C:\test\0001.vss')
```

Comment: For some reason this answer did not work for me, but I'm guessing it is some issue I have on my machine. It does make sense though. I did a work around by going into the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Visio Content\1033 directory and replacing one of those basic stencils which I will never use with my own custom stencil, and then accessing it through the old name - for instance 'IRRIG_U'.